# The charles 4.5.4 shows 304 (Not Modified) status code

Tags: ios, macos, charles-proxy

I am trying to capture the responses of my iOS application through Charles web proxy tool (version 4.5.4). My Mac version is Catalina 10.15.1.
After updating to the latest Charles proxy tool, for most of the API calls, I am getting 304 status code. I understand what 304 is, which is Not Modified https status. But it doesn't show the JSON response or at least I don't know how to see the response JSON.
If it's 200 status code I can see the response in Charles. I have attached the screenshot as an example to show how it looks like.
[image]

As you can see, if the response are showing "=" it is 304 redirection and if it shows "{}" it is 200 response. Is it my Charles problem or should I check with my iOS application. Any pointers will be much appreciated as I rely on Charles for my development purpose a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the server detects there is no response change, it would return **304 Not Modified** and **Empty body response**. It's how caching mechanism works.

You can by-pass it by enabling **No Caching** in Tool Menu, then the server will return the proper response.

Here is the document for [Charles Proxy's No Caching](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/no-caching/) or [Proxyman's No Caching](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/no-caching). Both are the same, but [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) is easier for debugging, especially for iOS development.

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware of the fact that we can explicitly set No caching for Charles. I tried that and it's working fine. I am upvoting your answer and marking your answer as accepted. Thanks for your inputs.